# Site URL is not a valid URL

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I'm having a hard time adding the domain http://blinksnap.com as the Site_uRL. It keeps saying "Site URL is not a valid URL". I can add any other domain like http://example.com. I'm really confused. Am I missing something ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblinksnap.com it gives the error "http://blinksnap.com/ is blocked or is being accessed too frequently, so we're not fetching it."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any Idea on how to correct the issue ?

Comment: Never seen this before and I'm not sure why you are getting the error. Perhaps you violated their TOS in some way?

Comment: Well, I don't even have a website yet - just trying to create my first app. It's weird !

Comment: yes it is. I meant I don't have a real website on there yet. It only has test code.

Comment: Try validating your source code... you have an h1 tag outside of the html...http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fblinksnap.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I contacted facebook support they gave me a link to register the problem. Hoping things will get cleared up soon.